# C++ copy constructor member pointer to function

Tags: c++

I read that we can use in case member pointer to function or array.
How I can write copy constructor and copy assignment if I have member type pointer to function or pointer to array.

```
class test {
public:
   test(const test& other) {
       // code
   }

   test& operator=(const test& other) {
       if (this != &other) {
            // code
       }

       return *this;
   }
private:
   int (*fnc_ptr)(int, int);
   int (*arr_ptr)[2];
};
```

Comment: That all depends on what you want your copy constructor and copy assignment to actually _do_.  Think that through.

Comment: Usually you don't need to write a custom copy constructor/assignment at all. The default one will copy pointers correctly. Unless there's something hackish you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you need *deep* or *shallow* copying? Note that this matters only for the pointer to the array (why do you have a pointer to an array anyway?), you can't do a deep copy of a function.

Comment: @freakish I'm _guessing_ that he wants to copy the (contents of) the array and is worried that he needs to do something special to copy the function pointer, but guessing is not what we do here.  And copying the array would not necessarily be 'hackish'.

Comment: @PaulSanders right, I thought he referred to the function pointer. Anyway C++ way is to use std vector/array instead of raw arrays. That will take care of deep copy automatically.

Comment: @freakish Yes, which might or might not be what he wants.  Which brings me back to my original comment.  That's what I wanted him to think about (my comment maybe too oblique, who can say, but I would flag this question as 'too broad' in triage anyway).

Comment: If I write constructors and assignment operator how I can copy deep or may be shallow.

Comment: Yes I want copy all items of array.

Comment: You should not use raw pointers to own memory. Also, if the pointer does own memory, then replacing it with `int arr[2];` would be simpler

Comment: No. I want understand how it work. 
I understand correct. I must:
1) allocate memory for pointer to array.
2) allocate memory for array.
3) and then copy